# Enabling outbound traffic on all network ports

Tags: networking, iptables, configuration, firewall, port

I am working on a network gateway implemented with a single board computer running Ubuntu (I can't confirm the version since it is not an off-the-shelf distro, it is built using buildroot). I am generating the system image with OEM provided toolchain and buildroot. I need to configure the OS image with a specific requirement that all the network ports need to be enabled for outbound communication.

I thought of doing it by running a shell script:

1. `netstat -na | grep <port_number>` If the response is blank, it means the port is not in use
2. If port is not in use, `sudo ufw allow <port_number>`
3. Repeat this till port 65536, using a loop.

Observations:

1. On local machine: The script takes a long time to execute, close to 2 hours. Might be because, it has a `echo` to print current port number. If I get rid of the echo the script gets stuck at the port whose property is being changed by `ufw allow` command.
2. On target hardware: `ufw: not found`.

I think the script is a dead-end. There has to be a better way to do this as a one-time configuration.
Are all the ports enabled for outbound traffic by-default?
Any idea where I need to look?

Comment: If you want to allow all outgoing traffic by default you can use `ufw default allow outgoing`.  That is the default already for ufw (see `ufw status verbose`) so it is unclear if that is your issue.

Comment: @toppk: I just checked on the target hardware, it doesn't have `ufw` support. The command returns `ufw: not found`. Sorry, I am a beginner when it comes to firewalls. A fundamental question would be *Are all the ports enabled for outbound traffic by-default?* as posted in OP.

Comment: well ufw is just a wrapper around iptables, so it's possible there is still some firewall in place, but most of these wrappers are default allow for outgoing.